# Two different Private Sub statements same code

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have received code for Access 2010 in VBA and there are two separate sub statements that contain the same code which is as follows:

```
Private Sub Test_Type_AfterUpdate()
    If Not IsNull(Me.Test_Type.Value) Then
        Me.TestNameID.Value = frmTestNameIDSmallToBigUpdate
        Me.Test.Value = frmTestSmallToMedUpdate
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Test_Type_Change()
    If Not IsNull(Me.Test_Type.Value) Then
        Me.TestNameID.Value = frmTestNameIDSmallToBigUpdate
        Me.Test.Value = frmTestSmallToMedUpdate
    End If
End Sub
```

Also other Private Sub statements contain the same coding but a different variable after If Not IsNull. I am new at VBA but have experience programming in Python and C#, is there a way to combine these statements into one statement.

Thanks

Comment: The code is exactly the same in both subs you added here. So I don't really see what you want to change. If the value after "IsNull" is different all the time (which is not in your example), then create an input param for a sub (e.g. "Private Sub Foo(ByRef inV As Variant)") and test IsNull on "inV" - call this function from all other functions, passing their input param. If you meant something else, please update your question to clarify

Comment: look up what [DRY Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) is ;)

Comment: Mark- the code is the same but one is suppose to run after a change to the form and one updates the form, I wanted to know if I actually needed both statements or combine them into one.  This is repeated throughout the access class object, one code for change the other for update.

Comment: What module is this contained in? Presumably within in a form?

Comment: Its within a form as an access class object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Create a third private sub to handle `Test_Type`'s events.

```
Private Sub HandleTestTypeEvent(object)
    If Not IsNull(object.Value) Then
        Me.TestNameID.Value = frmTestNameIDSmallToBigUpdate
        Me.Test.Value = frmTestSmallToMedUpdate
    End If
End Sub
```

And call it from your existing event procedures.

```
Private Sub Test_Type_AfterUpdate()
    HandleTestTypeEvent Me.TestType
End Sub

Private Sub Test_Type_Change()
    HandleTestTypeEvent Me.TestType
End Sub
```

Make sure properly type the parameter and give it a meaningful name.

If you're feeling *really* froggy, you can have a look at this.
[Overriding all Access form control AfterUpdate methods](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68221/overriding-all-access-form-control-afterupdate-methods)

Comment: hm... what about the `Me`? Did you just assume the `Me` refers to the correct object at all times?

Comment: @vba4all `Me` refers to the class (probably access form) that the code resides in. I'm assuming these event procedures all reside in the same class module. If not, you would have to pass `Me` as an argument as well.

Comment: This is not my code it's code that was previously written, and Me is used everywhere in the programming.

Comment: @marion my condolences. It's never fun maintaining somebody else's code base. `Me` is a self reference of the instance of the class it resides in. It's kind of a short cut. You may want to read [this Chip Pearson article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll look into the `Me` and will update the code based on everyone's comments. Thanks

Comment: There are six class objects all containing `Me` and one module.

Answer (score 0):

For better maintainability, refactor that code into a single sub that is called from both event subs, like this:

```
Private Sub Set_Test_NameID_and_Value
    If Not IsNull(Me.Test_Type.Value) Then
        Me.TestNameID.Value = frmTestNameIDSmallToBigUpdate
        Me.Test.Value = frmTestSmallToMedUpdate
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Test_Type_AfterUpdate()
    Call Set_Test_NameID_and_Value()
End Sub

Private Sub Test_Type_Change()
    Call Set_Test_NameID_and_Value()
End Sub
```

Comment: "but a different variable after If Not IsNull." ~ It needs a parameter for `Me.Test_Type`.

Comment: I understand about the variable and I will try the Call function for this and the other `Private sub` statements.

Comment: Assuming that the other code is also setting TestName.ID.Value and Test.Value after checking some other variable for Not IsNull, then yes it would be useful to parameterize the new sub.